# How to use tf.dataset for making predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I feel that using using tf.dataset is very intransparent how and why stuff works. I just hang out here and wonder how to make predictions now that I have a model using again a tf.dataset. It is so easy to use numpy arrays.

If I use a tf.dataset in tf.keras.predict(), how does this model know what is the data data to use as input and what are the labels? Because I have labels in my data where I want to do predictions... I don't understand the way of using and understand the inner working.

Thanks for enlightment.
EDIT:

Also since I need this for a custom callback I wonder if the output of predict with a datsset is aligned with the labels of the origin data structure? How could I extract the labels from the dataset of which I did predictions?

Edit:

I have scores of predict:

```
   scores=bert_model.predict(test)
```

where test is a tf.datsaet which ahs 4 column with names. I actually don't know how to display a datset. I just can iterate with take(). Then the 1. element look like this:

```
({'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([    3, 18414,  1169,    50, 18382,   239, 26972,     4, 11909,
         333,    30,  4445, 26918,   144,     4])>, 'token_type_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])>}, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>)
```

I just see that the last element has no key name? this is the label key.
So I think that internally the label key is ignored? Hopefully?

The first 3 keys should be used for predictions.

Also, Is the order of the result predictions the same as of the dataset used? Such that I can extract the labels from the dataset and do custom evaluation with the scores?

Comment: See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#training_evaluation_from_tfdata_datasets.

Comment: Sorry, but where is it about predict()? Also since I need this for a custom callback. Are the output of predcit with a datset alogned with the labels of the origin data structure?

Comment: `model.predict` returns a numpy array. Can you please post a minimal, reproducible example of the problem you are facing? Include code that users can run without having to change anything.

Comment: could  you have a look now?